# how to filter one dropdown list by change the other dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i am beginer in angular,in my project i have two drop down,first dropdown:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width">
            <mat-select  #captionlist2 (selectionChange)="filterByCaption($event)"> 
                 <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of list_product.data" [value]="p">
                       {{ p.description }}
                  </mat-option>
             </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and second dropdown:

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width">
           <mat-select  #brandlist (selectionChange)="filterByBrands($event)">
                  <mat-option  *ngFor="let m of list_brands.data" [value]="m">
                              {{ m.BDesc }}
                   </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

each dropdown fill from tables in ngOnInit() in type script:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.get_data_caption();
      this.get_data_brand();
}
get_data_caption(){
      this.DbSrvConnService.get_data_caption().subscribe(
          res => this.list_product.data = res
      );
  }
  get_data_brand(){
    this.DbSrvConnService.get_data_brands().subscribe(
       res => this.list_brands.data = res
   );
  }
```

also function for onchange caption dropdown:

```
filterByCaption(event: any)
          {
            console.log(event.value.id);
            this.list_brands.filterPredicate = 
             (data, filter: string) => data.brandcode== event.value.id;
               this.list_brands.filter=event.value.id;
          }
```

but second dropdown cannot be filtered by selection change first dropdown,How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `list_brands` and `list_product` is of type like:

```
interface YourFilterList<T> {
    data: T[];
    filterPredicate: (d: T, filter: string) => boolean;
    filter: string;
}
```

It seems to me that you're just missing some filter call on data. Something like:

```
filterByCaption(event: any){
   this.list_brands.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) =>
       data.brandcode == event.value.id;
   this.list_brands.filter = event.value.id;
   // This:
   this.list_brands.data = this.list_brands.data.filter(this.list_brands.filterPredicate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just make pipe who will return filtered array if something selected if first dd or nothing if first is null